remainder bound of Euler Maclaurin formula claimed by Aleksandar Ivic
In Aleksandar Ivic's Riemann Zeta Function book Chapter 1, between formula (1.8) and (1.9) he claims that the remainder term of the Euler Maclaurin formula $P_{2n+1}(t) = O(1)$. I don't see how this can be true since $P_m(0) = B_m$ is the Bernoulli number, which seems to grow pretty quickly. What's a sharp bound for $P_m(t)$? I guess to get analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ for $s > -n$, we only need $P_m(t)$ to be finite.
Update: to give a good bound for $B_{2k}$, note that
$$B_{2k} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1} 2 (2k)!}{(2\pi)^{2k}} \zeta(2k).$$
Now $\zeta(2k) = 1 + \sum_{n \geq n} n^{-2k} = 1 + O(2^{-2k + 1})$, by the integral bound, so $B_{2k}$ can be effectively bounded by the Stirling formula applied to $(2k)!$.

if you read carefully you see that $P_m$ is the periodic Bernoulli function so $B_m(t-[t])$ hence is obviously bounded by $\max |B_m[0,1]|=O(1)$

@Conrad thanks . As far as I can tell the Bernoulli numbers grow like $m!$. So I assume he meant $O_t(1)$ for any fixed $m$?

Here $n$ is fixed as we want extension to $\Re s>-n$ so the $O$ depends on $n$ but holds for all real $t$ in the integral
